# MySQL: Search keyword in a comment string

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I've looked through several similar topics on stackoverflow that is similar my question but I did not find anything that can help me yet. I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM twitter_result 
WHERE LOWER(TweetComment) LIKE LOWER('%lebron james%') 
AND LOWER(TweetComment) LIKE LOWER('%NBA%')
```

I want to search a TweetComment that contains the word "LeBron James" and "NBA" at a same time. But these two words need to stand alone by themselves. Like it should not return a tweet that contains #LeBron James and #NBA (or NBATalk)

For instance, it should return a tweet like this

`LeBron James Donates $41 Million To Send 1,100 Kids To College, Becomes 6th Most Charitable Athlete NBA In World`

where Lebron James and NBA stand alone (no `#` characters). I have the `LOWER` there to ignore the case sensitive. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Sorry I forgot to add, I am just using SQL in PHPMyAdmin

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you don't need the `LOWER()` function at all.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Sorry I am using SQL in PHPMyAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to use a `regexp` use,

```
select * from twitter_result
where --ignore tweets that contain #lebron james and #nba
      TweetComment not regexp '.*#lebron james.*|.*#nba.*' 
      --select only those tweets that contain lebron james AND nba
and   TweetComment regexp '[[:<:]]lebron james[[:>:]]'
and   TweetComment regexp '[[:<:]]nba[[:>:]]'
```

All the patterns being searched for, have to be stated explicitly as MySQL by default doesn't support lookarounds.

The above match is case insensitive by default. Use `regexp binary` if the search needs to be case sensitive. Add more search words as needed.

[Sample fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04788/2)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, vkp. I twisted your code a bit and I got this: `SELECT * FROM twitter_result WHERE TweetComment NOT REGEXP '.*#lebron james.*|.*#nba.*' AND TweetComment REGEXP '.*lebron james.*' AND TweetComment REGEXP '^nba[[:blank:]]|[[:blank:]]nba[[:blank:]]|[[:blank:]]nba$'` . It does not return a tweet that contains the word NBA at the end of the line like this tweet `RT @TalkingNBAHoops: 1. LeBron James
No debate, best player in the game
nba`

Comment: `TweetComment REGEXP '^nba[[:blank:]]|[[:blank:]]nba[[:blank:]]|[[:blank:]]nba$'` is not required. Use the *exact* query from the answer and you should see the expected row as the result.

Comment: I tried, it worked as if there is no # in front of the NBA. But some tweets are returned with the code contain the words like `@EstadisticasNBA:` , `@StrictlyNBATalk`, `@_eNBA`. I just want the word Lebron James and NBA stand alone. Any tip? I really appreciate for your help and time.

Comment: Try the edited version which checks for word boundaries.

Comment: Perfect ! Works like a charm ! Thank you sir !

Answer (score 2):

Although there are solutions using regular expressions, it is hard to propose one without knowing the database you are using.

Instead, you can remove the tags you don't want before doing the `like`:

```
WHERE REPLACE(LOWER(TweetComment), '#lebron james', '') LIKE LOWER('%lebron james%') AND
      REAPLCE(LOWER(TweetComment), '#nba', '') LIKE LOWER('%NBA%')
```

Comment: FWIW (and I know you know this, but just pointing it out to anyone who stumbles across this), `LOWER` should not be needed unless OP is using a collation that is case sensitive